# Why is definable compact equivalent to bounded and closed for sets with o-minimal structures?

Tags: model-theory, o-minimal, lo.logic

We have $M$ an o-minimal structure. $X \in M^n$ with the induced topology.
I'm reading an article which shows that $X \in M^n$ is definable compact is
equivalent to $X$ being bounded and closed.

Definable compactness of $X$ means that any $M$-definable curve in $X$ is completable.
(a curve in $X$ is a $M$-definable continuous embedding $f: (a,b) \rightarrow X$).
It is said to be completable if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+}}f(x)$ and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow b^{-}}f(x)$ exists.)

When it shows that any definably compact subset $X \in M^n$ is bounded I've got
the feeling that its proof is very complicated. I might be doing something wrong
but I've got the feeling that this proof can be done much more easily.

Here is how it goes: it first shows that definable compactness is preserved under 
projection on the k first coordinates.

Then it proceeds by induction.
let's assume that any definably compact subset $X \in M^n$ is bounded.
Let $X \in M^{n+1}$, then as $p(X)$ is definably compact (by preservation of
definable compactness under projection), it is by induction bounded ($p$ is the
projection onto the $n$ first coordinates).
So the first $n$ coordinates of X are bounded.

Now why can't we also say the projection of X onto his last n coordinates is
definably compact (by preservation of definable compactness under projection),
it is by induction bounded.
So the last n coordinates of X are bounded.

So X is bounded.

(for the proof of "Let $S \in M^n$ be definably compact and let $p : M^n \rightarrow M^k$
be a projection map. Then p(S) is definably compact." is the following:
By induction, it suffices to show that if $S \in M^{n+1}$ is definably
compact then p(S), where $p: M^{n+1} \rightarrow M^n$  denotes projection onto the
first n coordinates, is definably compact as well. For a contradiction, assume
not. Then there is a definable continuous embedding $f: (a, b) \rightarrow p(S)$
such that,say, f does not have a right-hand limit point in $p(S)$. By
o-minimality, for every $a \in p(S)$, the set $S_a = \{b \in M : (a, b) \in S\}$ is the union of
finitely many intervals. Since S is definably compact, $S_a$ is closed and bounded.
Let m(a) be the least element of $S_a$. We now define $g: (a, b) \rightarrow S$ by
$g(x) = (f(x),m(f(x))$. It follows that g does not have a right-hand limit
point in S since f does not have one in $p(S)$, a contradiction.)

Comment: This is a decent question, but can I suggest editing it and changing the title? With the title as is (and with no capital), it may not generate the interest it deserves.

Comment: I also added a tag.

Comment: This argument sounds OK to me. In fact, I think you don’t even need induction: just project $X$ on each coordinate individually.

Comment: It would help if you actually referenced *which* article you are reading; this proof appears in many places. Your suggested proof appears to work, but your question does not really tell us what the "complicated" proof in the original paper is.

Comment: I presume the paper is 
Definable Compactness and Definable Subgroups of o-minimal groups, 
by Ya'acv Peterzil and Charles Steinhorn. 
Journal of the London Mathematical Society (1999), 59: 769-786

Comment: Anyway, you need to prove that a subset of $M$ is definably compact if and only if it is bounded and closed. But this follows from the fact that definable functions $(a,b)\to M$ are piecewise monotonic.

Comment: @ACL: I'm just curious: why this paper in particular?

Comment: @Thierry: Why not? :-) Well, google pointed at it,this paper is the one where the definable compactness is introduced and shown to be equivalent to bounded & closed, and the proof is exactly as indicated by `unknown (google)'.